# PayPal IPN not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I tested a paypal donation button on localhost and it inserts the payment amount into the mysql database (verified on phpmyadmin) with the first time. but after that it just stops working

Is there anything below that could prevent it from working?

**config.php**

```
<?php

require "paypal_integration_class/paypal.class.php";
require "config.php";
require "connect.php";

$p = new paypal_class;
$p->paypal_url = $payPalURL;

if ($p->validate_ipn()) {
    if($p->ipn_data['payment_status']=='Completed')
    {
        $amount = $p->ipn_data['mc_gross'] - $p->ipn_data['mc_fee'];

        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO dc_donations (transaction_id,donor_email,amount,original_request)
                        VALUES (
                            '".esc($p->ipn_data['txn_id'])."',
                            '".esc($p->ipn_data['payer_email'])."',
                            ".(float)$amount.",
                            '".esc(http_build_query($_POST))."'
                        )");
    }
}

function esc($str)
{
    global $link;
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str,$link);
}
?>
```

**donation button**

```
<!-- The PayPal Donation Button -->



<form action="<?php echo $payPalURL?>" method="post" class="payPalForm">
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation" />

    <!-- Your PayPal email: -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $myPayPalEmail?>" />

    <!-- PayPal will send an IPN notification to this URL: -->
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $url.'/ipn.php'?>" /> 

    <!-- The return page to which the user is navigated after the donations is complete: -->
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $url.'/thankyou.php'?>" /> 

    <!-- Signifies that the transaction data will be passed to the return page by POST -->
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" /> 


    <!--    General configuration variables for the paypal landing page. Consult 
            http://www.paypal.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_std-variable-ref-donate.html for more info  -->

    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Go Back To The Site" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />




    <input type="double" name="amount">

    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donate_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />

    <!-- You can change the image of the button: -->
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />

  <img alt="" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is that you're only running the DB update if the payment has a status of completed.  It's possible your payments are pending and in those cases that code would be skipped, of course.

How exactly did you test locally?  Did you use the IPN simulator or did you run an actual sandbox transaction so the system would trigger just like a real order?  What is the actual value of your notify_url after the PHP is processed?  You're using $url, but what is the value of that?  If it's "localhost" it won't work.

Have you checked the PayPal IPN History to see if it shows the IPN's are getting sent and might be getting an error result?  Have you checked your web server logs to see if that script is getting hit?

Comment: I tested it by making payments to a sandbox account (i think this was the reason since the IPN statuses are all 'retrying'. $url is `$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);` which is localhost. It does insert details into the database the first time so i dont think localhost is the problem

Comment: If the status in IPN History is retrying that means it's getting a bad response.  If your actual value is localhost then there's no way that would when coming from PayPal.  To PayPal's server, localhosts is themselves, so you've got them sending IPN's to themselves, which of course is not what you're trying to do.  They're probably just getting 404 results because they don't have the same files you have on their server.  You must have something else going on with that first one that's working, cuz it can't be coming from PayPal if they're hitting localhost.